# Glob function gives only one result in C

Tags: c, glob

I have to program a shell in C and need to handle globing in it and I am only allowed to use the function glob. But when I try to use it, it only gives me one result back.

```
#include <glob.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int     main(int ac, char **av)
{
  glob_t    s;
  unsigned long  i = -1;

  if (glob(av[1], 0, NULL, &s))
    printf("ERROR !\n");
  else
    while (++i < s.gl_pathc)
      printf("%s\n", s.gl_pathv[i]);
  return (0);
}
```

I run this code in a folder where there is two C files : replace_glob.c and test.c

And when I run this code :

```
$ ./a.out *.c
replace_glob.c
$
```

I dont understand why and I would really appreciate your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the command line

```
./a.out *.c
```

the shell expands the glob pattern, so your program sees

```
{"./a.out", "replace_glob.c", "test.c", NULL}
```

as its `argv`. You need to quote the pattern for the program to see it:

```
./a.out '*.c'
```